# Small difference in types

Tags: syntax, f#

I have three functions that ought to be equal:

```
let add1 x = x + 1
let add2 = (+) 1
let add3 = (fun x -> x + 1)
```

Why do the types of these methods differ?
add1 and add3 are `int -> int`, but add2 is `(int -> int)`.
They all work as expected, I am just curious as to why FSI presents them differently?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is typically an unimportant distinction, but if you're really curious, see the [Arity Conformance for Values](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597609) section of the F# spec.

My quick summary would be that `(int -> int)` is a superset of `int -> int`.  Since `add1` and `add3` are syntactic functions, they are inferred to have the more specific type `int -> int`, while `add2` is a function value and is therefore inferred to have the type `(int -> int)` (and cannot be treated as an `int -> int`).

Comment: The part of the spec you referred to had to do with presenting functions to other languages, saying that only 'true' functions can implement int -> int. I made a C# project refer to an F# project, and sure enough, add1 and add3 are methods reachable from C# while add2 is presented as an FSharpFunc<int,int>!

Comment: i wondered about this too, thanks for clarifying. this is also the case with composed functions? ( ie let f = b >> m ) where f assumes parameter that is passed into b

Comment: @Alex - the only things which will be compiled as methods are syntactic functions (either `let f x = ...` or `let f = fun x -> ...`).  `let f = b >> m` is not a syntactic function: `f` is defined as the value obtained by applying the operator `(>>)` to values `b` and `m`.  I hope that answers your question.

Comment: So to close up, in order to make composed functions available to other languages you'll have to wrap them in another function, somewhat negating the 'higher-order' argument for F#, at least in interop scenarios? I don't see a good technical reason for this?

Comment: @Robert - you're welcome!  Regarding your question, other languages can invoke `FSharpFunction<_,_>` values without too much trouble, so it depends on how nice you want your API to look.  Typically, you'd probably only expose a small subset of your functions as part of a public API, so it wouldn't be too burdensome to wrap them in syntactic functions.

Comment: @kvb - Thanks, I know that you can invoke FSharpFunc from C#, but I wouldn't want to expose that. :)