# In F#, what is the meaning of parentheses around operator type?

Tags: f#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Small difference in types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093173/small-difference-in-types)

In `fsi`:

```
> (>);;
val it : ('a -> 'a -> bool) when 'a : comparison = <fun:it@12-2>

> (fun x y -> x > y);;
val it : 'a -> 'a -> bool when 'a : comparison = <fun:clo@15-4>
```

Why does first example have `()` around type definition, and second does not?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093173/small-difference-in-types/5093248#5093248

Comment: thanks, I'll propose closing as duplicate.